# Orderby listing issue

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

I installed the **`Post Expirator`** plugin in order to automatically classify active and expired post. I have to display the group of active post ordered by data and then the expired post ordered by date. Actually I have the following code, that is working fine except for the problem that it display the group of expired post first.

Please, how can I display the active post first and then the expired post?

```
$args = array(
'paged'            => $pager_page,
'orderby'          => array( 'date' => 'ASC', 'meta_value' => 'ASC' ),
'order'            => ($blog_index_sort_descending ? 'ASC' : 'DESC'),
'post_type'        => 'post',
'meta_key'         => '_expiration-date',
'post_status'      => 'publish');
```